# How can I cancel an ngEvent?

Tags: angularjs

With the release of AngularJS 1.2.0-rc.3, I was messing around with `ngCut`, `ngCopy`, and `ngPaste`, but I wasn't able to cancel them.  I figured the spec didn't allow for it, but it does.  It's got to be possible... can't really find anything by searching either (just about cancelling propagation).  Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/XEEpv/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean exactly by "cancel event" but what you can do with events is:

- `preventDefault()` so the default action that this event is normally triggering doesn't take place
- `stopPropagation()` so the event doesn't buble up in the DOM herarchy

I presume that you wanted to cancel default action, that is, call `preventDefault()` on the event:

```
$scope.cut = function ($event) {
    console.log('cut', $event);
    $event.preventDefault();
}
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/M5jRW/

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense to me now... Angular doesn't know that `$scope.cut` is bound to an event that can be canceled, so it doesn't care about the return value.  `preventDefault` and `$event.returnValue` (answered by John) get me what I want.  Seems though that `$event.returnValue` may be more in line with the Angular way, eh?

Comment: @Langdon not sure what criteria you've used to stamp `$event.returnValue` as "more AngularJS way" :-)

Comment: I think he means that `returnValue` is more in line with input/output while `preventDefault` is more of a side affect.

Comment: I guess to me, `preventDefault` is JavaScript and `$event.returnValue` is AngularJS, which was (I assume) explicitly created for returning false to cancel an event.  That's my assumption because I don't know of any other reason an event callback would need to return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `$event.returnValue` to false:

```
function x($scope) {
    $scope.cut = function ($event) {
        $event.returnValue = false;
        console.log('cut', $event);
    }
    $scope.kp = function ($event) {
        console.log('keypress', $event);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XEEpv/1/

Comment: $event.returnValue is now deprecated: *event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead*